# How to make objects accessible to other methods?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm doing a storage inventory program for my school. I just don't understand it fully because I lack knowledge in programming so I usually just watch videos in youtube.. How can I make the "arraylist object" accessible to the other methods below?

```
package ahaprogram2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AhaProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);`
        System.out.println("Hello! This is the AHA Program of Jalosjos,             Parreno and Alfonso");
        System.out.println("Please type the letter of your option");
        boolean loop  = false;

        while (loop != true) {
            showOptions();
            inputHandler();

            String contInput = reader.nextLine();
            if (contInput.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Input the name of Container 1: ");
                String ContInp1 = reader.nextLine();
                Container container1 = new Container(ContInp1);
                container1.printContainer();
            } 


            if (contInput.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("Input the name of Container 2: ");
                String ContInp2 = reader.nextLine();
                Container container2 = new Container(ContInp2);
                container2.printContainer();
            }

            if (contInput.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("Input the name of Container 3: ");
                String ContInp3 = reader.nextLine();
                Container container3 = new Container(ContInp3);
                container3.printContainer();
            }

            if (contInput.equals("4")) {
                System.out.println("Input the name of Container 4: ");
                String ContInp4 = reader.nextLine();
                Container container4 = new Container(ContInp4);
                container4.printContainer();

             }

             if (contInput.equals("5")) {
                 System.out.println("Input the name of Container 5: ");
                 String ContInp5 = reader.nextLine();
                 Container container5 = new Container(ContInp5);
                 container5.printContainer();
             }
        }
    }

    public static void showOptions() {
        System.out.println("A = Name Containers");
        System.out.println("B = Add Cans");
        System.out.println("C = Remove Cans");
        System.out.println("D = Display Cans");
        System.out.println("E = Quit");
        System.out.println("Type a Letter: ");
    }

    public static void inputHandler() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = reader.nextLine();

        if(input.equals("A")) {
             System.out.println("There are 5 containers.. What container 
          will you name? ");
             System.out.print("Type the number of your container: ");
        }

        if (input.equals("B")){
            System.out.println("Which container will you use?: ");
            System.out.print("Type a number for the container: ");
            String contforAdd = reader.nextLine();

            if (contforAdd.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("How many cans will you add?: ");
                int numofCans1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < numofCans1; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i+1) + " : ");
                    String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                    container1.AddCan();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

HERE IS THE OTHER CLASS FOR THE OBJECT & CONSTRUCTORS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Container { 
    Scanner reader  = new Scanner(System.in);
    public ArrayList<String> CanContainer = new ArrayList<String>();
    public int Contsizep;
    public String contName;

    public Container(String contname){
        this.contName = contname;
    }

    public void AddCan(String CantoAdd) {
        this.CanContainer.add(CantoAdd);
    }

    public void printContainer() {  // for OPTION A ONLY
        System.out.println("NAME SUCCESSFUL: **" + contName +"**");
    }
}
```

they cannot find the symbol "container1" because it's not declared inside the scope.. I have no idea in declaring it outside

Comment: You should really be asking your instructors about this very common aspect of Java. SO is not a great tutorial, which is sort of what you are asking for here. Hint: it sounds like you want a "getter" of some kind, but I hesitate to recommend any other answer because all of this really depends on your design and requirements, none of which we know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of a variable represents the part of the program within which the specific variable is accessible (to read up more on variable scopes in Java, I'd recommend reading [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) article).

With regards to your immediate concern/question, you create the variable `container1` within the following if statement:

```
if (contInput.equals("1")) {
    System.out.println("Input the name of Container 1: ");
    String ContInp1 = reader.nextLine();
    Container container1 = new Container(ContInp1);
    container1.printContainer();
}
```

This means that the scope of `container1`, or the part of the program within which other methods can access it, is limited to only this if statement. Your code tries to access `container1` within the function `inputHandler()` which is not only outside of the scope of `container1` but is also being called before `container1` is instantiated. In order to make `container1` accessible outside of this if statement then you will have to increase the scope of `container1`. The best way for you to do this would be to make it a static instance variable of your `AhaProgram` class. It would look something like this:

```
public class AhaProgram {

    private static Container container1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);`
        System.out.println("Hello! This is the AHA Program of Jalosjos,             Parreno and Alfonso");
        System.out.println("Please type the letter of your option");
        boolean loop  = false;

        while (loop != true) {
            showOptions();
            inputHandler();

            String contInput = reader.nextLine();
            if (contInput.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Input the name of Container 1: ");
                String ContInp1 = reader.nextLine();
                container1 = new Container(ContInp1);
                container1.printContainer();
            } 

          // ...the rest of your program...
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right, answer to your question:
Scope of your container1 variable is in "if" condition in "main" method. And this variable is visible only inside braces of this "if" condition. If you want to set this variable visible for another methods in this class you need make this a filed of this class. In your case it must be static filed.

```
public class AhaProgram {

private static Container container1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello! This is the AHA Program of Jalosjos,             Parreno and Alfonso");
    System.out.println("Please type the letter of your option");
    boolean loop  = false;

    while (loop != true) {
        showOptions();
        inputHandler();

        String contInput = reader.nextLine();
        if (contInput.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Input the name of Container 1: ");
            String ContInp1 = reader.nextLine();
            container1 = new Container(ContInp1);
            container1.printContainer();
        }
  //            ...
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Agree with jdv's comment.
To solve the issue for now you can make the variable as static field.

As a temporary solution I suggest this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class AhaProgram {

```
private static Container container;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello! This is the AHA Program of Jalosjos,Parreno and Alfonso");
            System.out.println("Please type the letter of your option");
    boolean loop  = false;

    while (loop != true)
    {

        showOptions();
        inputHandler();
        String contInput = reader.nextLine();


        if(contInput.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Input the name of Container 1: ");
            String ContInp1 = reader.nextLine();
            container = new Container(ContInp1);
            container.printContainer();

        }


        if (contInput.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("Input the name of Container 2: ");
            String ContInp2 = reader.nextLine();
            container = new Container(ContInp2);
            container.printContainer();
        }

        if (contInput.equals("3")) {
            System.out.println("Input the name of Container 3: ");
            String ContInp3 = reader.nextLine();
            container = new Container(ContInp3);
            container.printContainer();
        }

        if (contInput.equals("4")) {
            System.out.println("Input the name of Container 4: ");
            String ContInp4 = reader.nextLine();
            container = new Container(ContInp4);
            container.printContainer();

        }

        if (contInput.equals("5")) {
            System.out.println("Input the name of Container 5: ");
            String ContInp5 = reader.nextLine();
            container = new Container(ContInp5);
            container.printContainer();
        }

    }


}

public static void showOptions() {
    System.out.println("A = Name Containers");
    System.out.println("B = Add Cans");
    System.out.println("C = Remove Cans");
    System.out.println("D = Display Cans");
    System.out.println("E = Quit");
    System.out.println("Type a Letter: ");
}

public static void inputHandler() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = reader.nextLine();

    if(input.equals("A")){
        System.out.println("There are 5 containers.. What container will you name? ");
                System.out.print("Type the number of your container: ");


    }

    if (input.equals("B")){
        System.out.println("Which container will you use?: ");
        System.out.print("Type a number for the container: ");
        String contforAdd = reader.nextLine();

        if (contforAdd.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("How many cans will you add?: ");
            int numofCans1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < numofCans1; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i+1) + " :");
                        String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                container.AddCan(CanName);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Hope it helps !